# login php with permission level

Tags: php, sql, session, select

I have a problem in my code. I want separate logins, I want that when a login with Rank = 1 it redirect to a page when the rank is 0 = go to another is inserted. I tried to do but I had no result because it always sends to it. It was good if any of you could give me a little help.

```
<?php

require_once    'config.php';

$userName = $_POST["user-name"];
$userPass = $_POST["user-pass"];
$criptSen = hash("whirlpool", $userPass);
@$rediURL = $_GET["url"];

$SQL = mysql_query("SELECT Usuario, Senha FROM utilizadores WHERE Usuario='$userName'          AND Senha='$criptSen'");
    $query = mysql_query($SQL);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        $rank = $row["Rank"];
    }
if(mysql_num_rows($SQL) != 0){

session_start();

$_SESSION['Usuario'] = $userName;
$_SESSION['Senha']   = $criptSen;

if($rank = 0){

header("Location: membro.php");

} elseif($rank = 1) {

 header("Location: admin/index.php");

}

} else {

header("Location: index.php");

}

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
if($rank = 0){
```

To

```
if($rank == 0){
```

Also in the `else if`

And in your select you don't take the field `Rank` you're using in your `while` loop

```
$row["Rank"];
```

Change:

```
mysql_query("SELECT Usuario, Senha FROM...
```

To:

```
mysql_query("SELECT Usuario, Senha, Rank FROM...
```

**EDIT**

By the way, you should NOT use `mysql_` functions anymore. Those are deprecated. Use `mysqli_` instead

Comment: Well, I changed the code with these changes and gives.. `if($rank == 0){` and `} elseif($rank == 1) {` and `$SQL = mysql_query("SELECT Usuario, Senha, Rank FROM utilizadores WHERE Usuario='$userName' AND Senha='$criptSen'");`